# How can I handle the overflow in a carousel CSS animation?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a carousel with some images doing a ping pong effect from right to left and vice versa.
The problem is that I can't hide the overflow images when they go out the limits of its container.

Ex.: https://destinoarrakis.com/pruebas-php/

I've tried to use the overflow property but wasn't successful.

```css
.carroussel-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.carroussel-pelis {
  animation: carousel 100s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carroussel-elemento {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.carroussel-elemento>a>img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes carousel {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(-880px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carroussel-container">
  <div class="carroussel-pelis">
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carroussel-elemento">
      <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the Chrome Dev Tools to add `overflow: hidden` to your carroussel-container class and that seemed to do the trick?  Can you give that a try and then let us know if it's not working or if the effect is not really what you wanted?

Comment: What the...? Yes, it works (sigh). I think I need some rest...It was so evident...
Thanks for your time and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, as Jake said, you can add `overflow` property to `carroussel-container` class, you can add `overflow: hidden`